# Seaborn heatmap is combining multiple labels as xticks

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to plot a heatmap that displays diffternt causes of data breaches in a decade alongside the number of induividuals affected. The heatmap is displayed with no errors. However, the xicks is labelled by combining the year and Individuals Affected labels.

```py
causes_of_breaches_by_year = pd.DataFrame(
  df.groupby([
    'Breach Submission Year',
    'Type of Breach'])[['Individuals Affected']]
  .count())
  .reset_index()

causes_of_breaches_by_year['Individuals Affected'] =
    causes_of_breaches_by_year['Individuals Affected']
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(np.int64)

data_breaches_per_year_heatmap = causes_of_breaches_by_year.pivot(
    'Type of Breach',
    'Breach Submission Year'
  )

sns.heatmap(
    annot=True,
    cmap="YlGnBu",
    cbar_kws={'label': 'Individuals Affected'},
    data=data_breaches_per_year_heatmap
  )
  .set_title('Cause of Data Breach by Year')
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please include a picture of the resulting plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

When pivoting you have to give 3 params. See [pandas.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
DataFrame.pivot(index=None, columns=None, values=None)[source]
```

or in your case

```
piv = df.pivot(index='Type of Breach',
               columns='Breach Submission Year',
               values='Individuals Affected'
               )
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Breach Submission Year': ['2018', '2018', '2018', '2019', '2019', '2019'],
    'Type of Breach': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Individuals Affected': [1, 2, 6, 2, 5, 6]
})

piv = df.pivot('Type of Breach', 'Breach Submission Year',
               'Individuals Affected')
piv = df.pivot(index='Type of Breach',
               columns='Breach Submission Year',
               values='Individuals Affected'
               )

sns.heatmap(
    annot=True,
    cmap="YlGnBu",
    cbar_kws={'label': 'Individuals Affected'},
    data=piv
).set_title('Cause of Data Breach by Year')

plt.show()
```

[image]